# New questions based on trying to anwser old questions

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I was working on a more mathematical answer to [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/11026/how-does-extracellular-potassium-ion-concentration-and-calcium-ion-concentration) question and realized my reasoning was wrong, and something more subtle was going on. Reading the answers didn't seem to explain my faulty reasoning either. In fact they in a way supported my reasoning.

Anyway I have some hypothesis of why I am wrong and what could be the explanation but these are just guesses. As they are not backed by any evidence I'd like to ask the community if I am on the right track. That being said it is a question that's been ask before.

So question for Meta: Is it okay to ask a new question, based of an old question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we generally expect answered to be backed up by some kind of evidences or references, it is okay to ask a question based on a previous one given that it has an upvoted answer.

You should, however, explain what approach you took or what hypothesis you considered and why you think it may be wrong. This builds a good background for the question. You should also explicitly mention why your question is different from the previous one so as to avoid your question being classified as a duplicate.